# Python: Fins String on File and return rext

Tags: python, string, file

I´m trying to find a specific string on a file and have it return the text in front of if.

The file has the following:  `"releaseDate": "2022-07-11T07:15:00.000Z"`

I want to search the releaseDate but have it return the `2022-07-11T07:15:00.000Z`

I can find it, but have honestly no idea how to return the info I need.

```
dateOccurence=open('scriptFile.txt', 'r').read().find('releaseDate')
```

Comment: can you share what scriptFile contains ? Seem slike JSON content

Comment: @azro its quite big, so I uploaded to https://justpaste.it/8lty1

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question should include all information which is needed to solve your problem. If it is too big, just share a little sample of your data (not as image! copy/paste it from your editor)

Comment: I looked at the data, seemed JSON, but there some mistake in it so either you pasted bad, or it's broken content. But see my answer, regex will solve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is JSON content, so parsing it as this would be the best idea, but then you'd need to know the path of keys to reach it

A regex approach is easier here

```
with open('scriptFile.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()

date = re.search(r'"releaseDate":\s+"([^"]+)"', content)[1]
print(date)  # 2022-07-11T07:15:00.000Z
```

Comment: if i want to search "color":"white/barley/blanco",, what would i need to change in your approach?

Comment: @Crapts replace `releaseDate` by `color`